# How to concatenate two dates into one string in Django?

Tags: python, django, orm

I have two model fields.

```
class Event(models.Model):]
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I would like to concatenate two dates into one string I would like to obtain result like this as new field:

**{'dates': '2020-12-1-2021-12-1'}**

concatenate start_date and end_date into one string

What I tried to do:

```
event = Event.objects.annotate(dates=Concat('start_date__date', 'end_date__date'))
event.values('dates')
```

Output:

```
<QuerySet [{'dates': '2020-12-25 17:44:50+002021-01-16 17:44:52+00'}],
```

Not output I would like to obtain

I need output like this:

**{'dates': '2020-12-1-2021-12-1'}**

Concatenate two date time fields into one string (only dates, don't need time)

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
event = Event.objects.dates('start_date__date', 'end_date__date').annotate(dates=Concat('start_date__date', 'end_date__date'))
```

Comment: I think, the Answer  is clear and it does not any declaration.

Comment: That is your choice :) I provided the links for you to know better and maybe improve your post.